# A function from an itemshop I integrated for my metin2 server doesn't work, the donation one to be more precise

Tags: php, error-log

this is the errorlog I get:
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /home/metin2cox/public_html/itemshop/include/functions/header.php on line 196

what I have at these lines:

```
{
    if(!$account->checkStatus($_SESSION['id']))
    {
        $account->doLogout();
        
        header("Location: ".$shop_url);
        die();
    }
    $categories = $shop->getAllCategories();
    $categoriesbyid = array();
    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        $categoriesbyid[$category['id']]['icon'] = $category['icon'];
        
        if($category[$_SESSION['lang']]!=null && $category[$_SESSION['lang']]!='')
            $categoriesbyid[$category['id']]['name'] = $category[$_SESSION['lang']];
        else if($category['en']!=null && $category['en']!='')
            $categoriesbyid[$category['id']]['name'] = $category['en'];
        else if($category['ro']!=null && $category['ro']!='')
            $categoriesbyid[$category['id']]['name'] = $category['ro'];
        else
        {
            foreach($languages as $key => $lang)
                if(!in_array($key, [$_SESSION['lang'], 'ro', 'en']) && $category[$key]!=null && $category[$key]!='')
                    $categoriesbyid[$category['id']]['name'] = $category[$key];
        }
        if(!isset($categoriesbyid[$category['id']]['name']))
            $categoriesbyid[$category['id']]['name'] = 'CAT '.$id;
    }
```

line 196 is this one:
$categoriesbyid[$category['id']]['name'] = 'CAT '.$id;

Comment: Well the error is quite descriptive, the code is missing the `$id` variable. I'm not entirely sure on how this is expected to work but I assume you can replace the `$id` with `$category['id']`.

Comment: did it, still not working but I don't get any errorlog now xD